# i cant browse my site

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I just hosted my website and am having some difficulties. i used the codeigniter frame work. The issue is this, when I try loading my site, it loads the index page well alright but the minute I try to browse to other pages it comes up with this error,

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

my htaccess file was wrong, this is the right configuration. hope this helps anyone that gets in the same mess. thanks to all who gave their time. :-)

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|(.*).swf|user_guide|profiles|images|min|assets|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Your CI installation may have an `.htaccess` file, post it's contents and check your server error logs. [More here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite) for details.

Comment: Is it your own server? or a shared hosting provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More often than not, CodeIgniter doesn't detect the `uri_protocol` properly. That results in the index page loading, but other pages 404ing. Check your `uri_protocol` in config.php. I've had most luck with setting it to `PATH_INFO` instead of `AUTO`.

On most shared shared hosts, `mod_rewrite` is enabled by default. Check phpinfo(). Also, your `.htaccess` file should looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're using apache, you must install and configure mod_rewrite module.

Comment: how can i get that and install?

Comment: check apache's rewrite guide @ http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html